# Display android numeric keyboard for an input that can accept letters as well

Tags: android

I have input boxes for a slider. When these are selected I would like the numeric keyboard to appear on all mobile devices as the user can only enter numbers. However when the user uses the slider, I want the boxes to be able to display the number with SI multipliers ('1000' as '1k').

As far as I can tell I need to keep the type as text to be bale to use any letters.

Is there any way to show the numeric keyboard for text inputs, or any other way to get the effect I want?

Thanks in advance for any answers or other information.

Comment: what you have done so far ?

Comment: @MahaKhan I've tried using a pattern parameter to restrict the characters that can be entered. From what I've read this only works on iphones (I don't have one to test with), and it probably won't work if I allow k,M,G etc., min and max, as I need for it's current operation.
I've also tried setting the type to numeric, but this won't allow any letters at all.